# How can I test I function that returns an applyDecorators in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I am writing a jest test to a function that returns a called function apllyDecorators(...DecoratorsToAPlly). But I cant find the right way to set my test code.

It appears to have some problem in verify called functions.

My code:

```
import * as nestjs from '@nestjs/common';
    describe('TestOperationsDefaultResponses', () => {
      const defaultConfigsObjects = {
        200: ApiResponse({ status: 200, description: 'OK' }),
        400: ApiResponse({ status: 400, description: 'Bad Request' }),
        401: ApiResponse({ status: 401, description: 'Unauthorized' }),
        403: ApiResponse({ status: 403, description: 'Forbidden' }),
        408: ApiResponse({ status: 408, description: 'Request Timeout' }),
        500: ApiResponse({ status: 500, description: 'Internal Server Error' }),
      };
      describe('root', () => {
        console.log(
          OperationsDefaultResponses(statusConfigPatternsDict.standardGet),
        );
        it('should match response object', () => {
          expect(
            {}.valueOf.call(
              OperationsDefaultResponses(statusConfigPatternsDict.standardGet),
            ),
          ).toEqual(
            applyDecorators(
              defaultConfigsObjects[200],
              defaultConfigsObjects[400],
              defaultConfigsObjects[401],
              defaultConfigsObjects[403],
              defaultConfigsObjects[408],
              defaultConfigsObjects[500],
            ),
          );
        });
      });
    });


Tests Result:

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    
        Expected: [Function anonymous]
        Received: serializes to the same string       
    
          26 |           OperationsDefaultResponses(statusConfigPatternsDict.standardGet),
          27 |         ),
        > 28 |       ).toEqual(
             |         ^
          29 |         applyDecorators(
          30 |           defaultConfigsObjects[200],  
          31 |           defaultConfigsObjects[400], 




Ive tried many variations of this, but nothing has worked by now.


Updated:  tried to do this with another aproach, as suggested by @JayMcDoniel, by using a spy  to track what arguments were called. But it is is still failing. My new code:






describe('TestOperationsDefaultResponses', () => {
  const defaultConfigsObjects = {
    200: ApiResponse({ status: 200, description: 'OK' }),
    400: ApiResponse({ status: 400, description: 'Bad Request' }),
    401: ApiResponse({ status: 401, description: 'Unauthorized' }),
    403: ApiResponse({ status: 403, description: 'Forbidden' }),
    408: ApiResponse({ status: 408, description: 'Request Timeout' }),
    500: ApiResponse({ status: 500, description: 'Internal Server Error' }),
  };

  describe('root', () => {
    const applyDecSpy = jest.spyOn(nestjs, 'applyDecorators');
    it('should match applied args', () => {
      expect(applyDecSpy).toBeCalledWith(
        defaultConfigsObjects[200],
        defaultConfigsObjects[400],
        defaultConfigsObjects[401],
        defaultConfigsObjects[403],
        defaultConfigsObjects[408],
        defaultConfigsObjects[500],
      );
    });
  });
});
```

error ive got:

```
 FAIL  ./operation-default-responses-decorator.spec.ts 
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: applyDecorators
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)       

      18 |
      19 |   describe('root', () => {
    > 20 |     const applyDecSpy = jest.spyOn(nestjs, 'applyDecorators');
         |                              ^
      21 |     it('should match applied args', () => { 
      22 |       expect(applyDecSpy).toBeCalledWith(   
      23 |         defaultConfigsObjects[200],

      at ModuleMocker.spyOn (../node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:726:16)
```

Aftrt all, I think this second way is the better aproach, but for some reason I cant set it up with a nestjs/common function

Comment: Is there a reason you want to test it? You're pretty much just asserting that the function from Nest acts correctly, which should already be tested, right?

Comment: I recommend you to read this article: [Selective Unit Testing – Costs and Benefits](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/11/04/selective-unit-testing-costs-and-benefits/)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel  note that I am not testing the applyDecorators() native nestjs funtion, but I am testing my own implemented operationsDefaultResponses() function, and this function needs to return an applyDecorators call with multiple args.

Comment: @MicaelLevi thanks, interesting artice. I my case it just aims to be a simple unit test to a function that could receive some feature addittions futurely, then I think automated test in this case could help me know if everthing is going ok.

Comment: @YuriSilva it might be helpful to _see_ the implementation of `OperationsDefaultResponses` so that we can understand better. You may just need to end up mocking `applyDecorators` so that you can assert it was called with the proper values

Comment: @JayMcDoniel think that would solve my problem, man. But one time my  OperationsDefaultResponses function (its actually a custom decorator) is importing applyDecorators method from @nestjs/common, is it possible to make it use/import a mock applyDecorators function instead? How could I make this using jest?

Comment: `import * as nestjs from '@nestjs/common'` combined with `const applyDecSpy = jest.spyOn(nestjs, 'applyDecorators')` and now you can verify the `applyDecSpy` was called with what you expect

Comment: Man i had already tried to do this that way before, but having another error.  But seeing your point, I think that it is actually the better aproach to do this that way. Then I will post more information about the code and the errors Ive received doing this that way, with the spyOn method.